# Nested Constraint - Constrain Entry Based On Another Table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have three tables: Facility, Project, System.

Facility . FacilityID is the PK within the Facility table.
Project . ProjectID is the PK within the Project table.
System . SystemID is the PK within the System table.

A project can only be associated with one facility. This one-to -many relationship is established via the FK Facility . FacilityID - Project.FacilityID within the Project table.

A facility can have many systems. This one-to-many relationship is established via the FK Facility . FacilityID – System . FacilityID within the System table.

A column is also needed within the System table to store the ProjectID for the most recent project that affects that system. How can I add a constraint that only allows the entry of a ProjectID value that is valid for the FacilityID of that System table row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Project contains ProjectID and FacilityID, and System contains SystemID, FacilityID and ProjectID.

You can create a compound Index on Project made of ProjectID and FacilityID, and then create a compound FK in System of ProjectID and FacilityID linked to the new index on System.